# Prevent Ruby ActionMailer from removing carriage returns (Windows line endings) from txt file attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm trying to send a file attachment using Rubys ActionMailer. However, when I send my file, the carriage returns "\r" that I've added are removed.

```
string = "the quick brown\r\nfox jumped over\r\nthe bridge"

File.open(file = "attachment_#{Time.now.to_i}.txt", "w+") do |f|
  f.write(string)
end

attachments['test_file.txt'] = {
  mime_type: 'text/plain',
  content: string
}

mail(
  :to => 'somebody@example.com',
  :from => 'somebody@example.com',
  :subject => 'Message Test'
).deliver
```

The file that is written has the proper line endings, but the attached file has the carriage returns removed. How I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

So just wanted to post my solution in case anyone else ends up with this issue...

After checking the base64 encoded attachment from the email, I found that the string, did in fact, not have the carriage return.

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > Base64.decode64('dGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duCmZveCBqdW1wZWQgb3Zlcgp0aGUgYnJpZGdlCg==')
=> "the quick brown\nfox jumped over\nthe bridge\n"
```

This led me to believe that the ActionMailer was in fact reformatting my email before it was encoded. I figured that I could just encode the message body manually and send it over ....

```
encoded = Base64.encode64(string)
attachments['test_file.txt'] = {
  mime_type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
  encoding: 'base64',
  content: encoded
}
```

And that seems to have done the trick. My attachment now contains carriage return and line feed endings ("\r\n")

I'm not sure if this is expected functionality for the ActionMailer. I definitely didn't expect it.